# How to add watermark to video easily and quickly?

Tags: video, video-editing, watermark

How to add watermark to video easily and quickly?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to download [Virtualdub.](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/Virtualdub) Then just follow the instructions [here...](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/191496-Put-a-custom-watermark-on-your-video)

Answer (score 0):

Adding watermark to video is pretty easy. Here, I recommend you two options:

1. [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) is so popular that few people are unaware of it. It supports adding watermark to video too. The following is the detailed steps on how to add watermark to video with VLC.

   > 1. Download and install VLC. After launch it, click "Media" to load the video that you want to add watermark to.
   > 2. Click "Tools" on toolbar and choose "Effect and Filters" from the drop-down menu. And a new window named "Adjustments and Effects" opens.
   > 3. In the new window, switch to "Video Effects" tab and click "Logo" section. Check "Add logo" box and paste the URL of the image file.
   > 4. In the same section, adjust the logo position and transparency.
   > 5. Click "Close" to finish adding watermark to video.
2. A step by step guide on [how to add watermark to video](http://www.faasoft.com/articles/add-watermark-to-video.html).

Comment: (1) Where is the first option from? Identify your source. (2) Don’t just post a link; post the essential parts of the second option.

Comment: and how do you then save this to a new file?